# Flutter Bottom Navigation Bar pads twice for keyboard

Tags: android, flutter, bottomnavigationview

Having problem with BottomNavigationBar where it increases in height when the keyboard is up

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvqTP.png)

[After focused on TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZynb.png)

Would really appreciate insight on this problem. Thank you very much!

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.all_inclusive), title: new Text("Hello"), backgroundColor: Colors.cyan),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text("Hello"), backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen),
        ],
      ),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new TextField(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like this known issue. 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12084

If there are more than one scaffold, the padding is added once for each scaffold.

Comment: But there is only 1 scaffold in my case (above code). And in my project this issue arised all of a sudden, and I had no way of isolating it. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the `MaterialApp` contains one already. I'm not yet familiar with the widgets. Did you check the example apps how they do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
Scaffold(
        ...
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        ...
}
```

try this.
There was a large space between keyboard and input field in my case.
(not totally the same, my tab bar was normal)

I solved it by setting this property. I have no idea if it would work in your case. Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

IN my case there i used  `MaterialApp` and inside that i was using `Scaffold` simply `removing MaterialApp` fixed causing issue .